# Progress bar update While button is being pressed doesn't work in a fragment

Tags: android-fragments

This code works PROPERLY in a activity but not in a fragment, for some reason when the button is down and it gets into the runnable the question button.ispressed() returns false. I can't understand.

```
  button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    arg0.post(rotationRunnable);
            } else if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                progress.setProgress(0);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


  public Runnable rotationRunnable = new Runnable() {
    int mProgressStatus = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(button.isPressed()) {
                if (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                    mProgressStatus++;
                    progress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    button.postDelayed(rotationRunnable, 20);
                } else {
                    sendMessageToService("");
                    mProgressStatus = 0;
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            } else {
                if (mProgressStatus > 0) {
                    mProgressStatus--;
                    progress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    button.postDelayed(rotationRunnable, 20);
                    if (mProgressStatus == 0) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e)
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It seems to be the button in the fragment has a small delay so when I ask in the runnable if the button is pressing returns false, so if I call the runnable with a delay it returns true. It´s a bit a strange but works...

```
arg0.postDelay(rotationRunnable, 200);
```